# Limit OWL Carousel's displayed items

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to limit the humber of items displayed in OWL Carousel. I have 8 items that displayed in 4 items in the window. I want only to appear 4 items instead 8, I tried with items: '4' but it only displays the items that u want to see in the display, not the total items.

Documentation: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

Comment: There is no way to set a limit of the total number of items with owl this would be set in the code you have that generates the markup before owl starts, so if you only want 4 items then you would only output 4 items into the markup.

Answer (score 0):

As Ginger CSS Wizard wrote, there is no way to set a limit of the total number of items.

If you only need to see the first 4 items and the others not, just remove them before calling owlCarousel. eg.:

```
$i=0;
$('.owl-carousel .item').each(function(){
  if($i>3){
    $(this).remove();
  }
  $i++;
});
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
```